# How can I log lftp errors in bash script

Tags: bash, lftp

I'm writing a bash script to download/upload files using lftp with logging  enable to file (`set xfer:log-file "$LOGFILE"`).

During my tests I had an `550 access denied error` but to my surprise the error went to stdout instead of going into my logfile and I found no way of capturing the error. I'm pasting my upload function below.

```
function xfer_up(){
  FOUND=$(ls $OUTBOX | wc -l)
  if [ $FOUND <= 0]; then
    log_info "no files available at $2 (EMPTY FOLDER)."
    return
  fi
  log_info "transfering files from $FOUND into $1/$2"
  lftp -u ${USER},${PASSWD} $1 << LFTP
set xfer:log true
set xfer:log-file "$LOGFILE"
set xfer:clobber true
set xfer:auto-rename true
debug 3
mput $OUTBOX/*.txt -O $2
quit
LFTP
}
```

Any ideas about how can I log this errors?

Comment: _Where_ do you want to log lftp errors ?

Comment: `[ $FOUND <= 0]` is a invalid syntax. The should be a space between `0` and `]`.

Comment: @KamilCuk preferably into $LOGFILE (which points to /var/log/file-transfer.log). Great catch on the typo.

Answer (score 3):

Just redirect and append standard output and standard error output to the logfile.

```
lftp -u ${USER},${PASSWD} $1 2>>"$LOGFILE" >>"$LOGFILE" <<LFTP
```

Comment: I tried to redirect but the error message (`mput: Access failed: 553 Could not create file. (outbox/test.txt)`) still only printing on the console.

Comment: Increasing the debug level does **not** log all errors and warnings (e.g. clobber not set)! Redirecting stderr does. Even if OP could solve his problem with the debug it is not a correct answer to this question. This should be the accepted answer. FYI: `lftp sftp://$IP:$PORT -u"$USERNAME","$PASSWORD" -e "set xfer:log-file $download_log;get $FILE;" >> $download_log 2>&1` does the same as above with another style.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. The debug directive can point to a file so adjusting `debug` to `debug -t -o $LOGDIR/debug.log 9` (where 9 is the debug level) did the trick. To log only the received messages (ie remote responses) use the log level 4 or 5 instead of 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach and be able to save the debug log where you can refer later when you want to check what happened. example with all variables

```
lftp -d -u ${ftpUser},${ftpPasswd} ${ftpUrl} << EOF
set xfer:clobber on;
set net:max-retries 2;
debug -t -o debug.log 9
set ssl:verify-certificate no;
cd  ${FOLDER_LOCATION}
mget ${VERSION}*.zip
bye
EOF
```